# When I create a file through code I can't see it in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, file, build, jar

So I'm making a game engine in java, it has two parts: the editor and the game engine itself.
In the editor I serialize Scene objects and write them into .scene files for the engine to read, but the file doesn't show up in eclipse, I can see it in the file explorer so it is created. for a while I didn't pay attention because I can still read the file using the `File` class. But then I tried exporting it into a runnable jar file and the build didn't work, so I tried using `getClass().getResource("path")` and I ran into issues, as I understand the file is not being added to the build path for some weird reason even thou it's in the src folder, can I add the file to the build path programmatically or do I need to do something else?

Here is some code:

```
public File createSceneFile(String path) {
    try {
        File file = new File(path);
        
        if(file.createNewFile()) {
            FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);
            os.writeObject(scene);
            os.close();
        }
            
        return file;
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
    
public File updateScene(String path) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);
        os.writeObject(scene);
        os.close();
        
        return new File(path);
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Code to read the .scene files:

```
public Scene getScene(URL url) {
    try {
        InputStream inStream = url.openStream();
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inStream);
        Scene s = null;
        try {
            s = (Scene)ois.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ois.close();
        
        s.instantiation = this;
        return s;
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use 'File > Refresh' to get Eclipse to pick up files that have been added to the workspace.

Comment: Are you using a build tool like Maven or Gradle? In that case it would matter where exactly you put the files in your src directories. Normally they should go to `src/main/resources` and your build should pick them up there and put then into the root of the jar file.

Comment: @greg-449 it doesn't work for some reason

Comment: @Thomas no I don't, I use the default java compiler

Comment: So you're just using plain `javac` commands or let Eclipse do the building and packaging?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to refresh the project so that Eclipse sees that the new file has been added. Select the project and hit F5.